# How to extract a number using regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to regular expressions and ruby. below is the example which I start working with

```
words= "apple[12345]: {123123}  boy 1233 6F74 2AC 28458 1594 6532 1500 D242g
apple[13123]: {123123123} girl Aui817E 9AD453 91321SDF 3423FS 1213FDAS 110FADA4 43ADAC0 1AADS4D8 BASAA24 "
```

I want to extract `boy 1233 6F74 .. to  .. D242g` in an array 
Similarly I want to extract `girl Aui817E 9AD453 .. to .. 43ADAC0 1AADS4D8 BASAA24` in an array

I did tried to this could not do it. Can some one please help me to this simple exercise. 
Thanks in advance.

```
begin
     pattern = /apple\[\d+\]: \{\d+\} (\w) (\d+) (\d+) /
      f = pattern.match(words)
      puts " #{f}"
end
```

Comment: You have two spaces just  before `boy`, while your regexp claims to look for the only one. Try: `/apple\[\d+\]:\s+\{\d+\}\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
words.scan(/apple\[\d+\]: \{\d+\}(.+)/).map{|a| a.first.scan(/\S+/)}
```

or

```
words.each_line.map{|s| s.split.drop(2)}
```

Output:

```
[
  ["boy", "1233", "6F74", "2AC", "28458", "1594", "6532", "1500", "D242g"],
  ["girl", "Aui817E", "9AD453", "91321SDF", "3423FS", "1213FDAS", "110FADA4", "43ADAC0", "1AADS4D8", "BASAA24"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = words.scan(/apple\[\d+\]: {\d+}(.+)/).flatten.map { |line| line.scan(/\w+/) }
```

(`{` and `}` are not need to escape on regex.)

return

```
[
  ["boy", "1233", "6F74", "2AC", "28458", "1594", "6532", "1500", "D242g"],
  ["girl", "Aui817E", "9AD453", "91321SDF", "3423FS", "1213FDAS", "110FADA4", "43ADAC0", "1AADS4D8", "BASAA24"]
]
```

`array[0]` gives an array start with "boy", and `array[1]` gives an array start with "girl".